# GestureRecognizer doesn't work on TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to find a way to hide the keyboard as soon as the user taps elsewhere on the screen after filtering the content of my tableview.

But somehow when I add an UITapGestureRecognizer my TableView freezes and it's impossible to go further into the application.

Here's what I do :

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func dismissKeyboard() {

    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I've tried this on a Blank ViewController with a TextField and it works. What am I missing? Is there a specific way to add GestureRecognizer to table views? Because as soon I add the Gesture it breaks everything. I also tried using resignFirstResponder with the same results.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `cancelsTouchesInView` variable to false. This defaults to true, by setting it to false you allow the touches to be responded to by your gesture and then pass through your gesture back down to the view so the tableView can respond as well.

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

[Documentation on Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/cancelsTouchesInView)

Discussion Excerpt from Docs:

> When this property is true (the default) and the receiver recognizes its gesture, the touches of that gesture that are pending are not delivered to the view and previously delivered touches are cancelled through a touchesCancelled:withEvent: message sent to the view. If a gesture recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture or if the value of this property is false, the view receives all touches in the multi-touch sequence.

Comment: That was it thanks a lot. Can't believe I didn't find a link talking about this. Also why is this even set to true in the first place? Since it's conflicting with other touches and screwed most of my events in my Table/Collection views.